# Error with paths in git, cannot create directory at ... Invalid argument

Tags: javascript, laravel, git

When trying to pull the branch or do 'reset --hard' occurs an error (working tree before launching this commands was clean)

```
error: Invalid path '<path_to_project_locally>\storage\logs/laravel-2020-08-30.log'
fatal: cannot create directory at 'public/<path_to_project_locally>\storage\logs': Invalid argument
```

Deleting laravel-2020-08-30.log didn't helped, despite this folder is ignored by git(so this file exists only locally, but not in the repo).
When trying to clone this project to a new empty folder, the same error occurs.
Never seen this error before, while worked with this project.

Do anyone has any ideas what's going on and how to fix this?

Comment: Give _write_ permission to **storage\logs** directory. I think chmod 775 is appropriate and then add the user you are using to login to the _www-data_ usergroup. Then it should work.

Comment: @sta How to add this permission?

Comment: Which kind of server you are using?